# What does "Mobile devices" mean on the Steam product install page?

Tags: steam

When installing a game on my Steam library, I noticed a dropdown beside the INSTALL button. On this dropdown, it has two options:

- This computer
- Mobile devices

[image]

However, this dropdown does not appear on other non-installed games in my library. So what is this for? I can't seem to find any information about it on the internet.

Clicking on "Mobile devices" does nothing.

Comment: I have a Steam Deck and this option doesn't seem to be related to it: this option does nothing even if I connect my devices together via Remote Play

Comment: Could it be related to Steam link?

Comment: @pinckerman if so then why does it only show up in select titles and not others when I can stream all of the games in my library?